# Colocando um vídeo dinâmico do YouTube em um <iframe> (asp.net)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, iframe

Boa noite! Estou tentando colocar um vídeo do youtube baseando-se em uma url guardada em um banco de dados sql, o problema é que a forma que eu achei de colocar, funciona apenas com alguma url estática, no seguinte modo:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/o_l4Ab5FRwM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Estou tentando colocar um valor variavel para src, pensei em uma label e depois atribuir no .Text, mas não funciona pois o Iframe para quando insiro a label no meio dele ... alguém tem ideia do que eu posso fazer?

Obrigado :D

Answer (score 1):

Essa variável é server-side ou client-side? Nestes casos você tem duas soluções:

**Exemplo 1:** utilizar o atributo src do iframe.

```js
// Captura elementos iframe, pode utilizar o método getElementById
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
iframe[0].src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/o_l4Ab5FRwM";
```

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**Exemplo 2** :Construir o iframe dinamicamente via javascript.

```js
var iframe2 = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe2.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/o_l4Ab5FRwM";
iframe2.width = 560;
iframe2.height = 315;
iframe2.frameborder = 0;
iframe2.allowfullscreen = true;
document.body.appendChild(iframe2);
```